# Are these sentences OK?

Tags: sentence

Are these sentences OK?

> Other notation and terminology which we don't define will be used as in the John's book.
>
> In other notation and terminology we will follow John's book.

Comment: What do you think is wrong with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"For notation and terminology not defined in this book, please(or we) refer to John's book"

OR

"All notation and terminology not defined in this book are based on John's book"

I am assuming you have a more formal name for John's book so that the word "book" is not repeated.